# moodle: how to change webservice message from xml to json

Tags: json, web-services, rest, moodle

I want to use json format for moodle webservices 
I have configured REST protocol in 
Site administration / ► Plugins / ► Web services / ► Manage protocols

but when I try this call from browser 
http://localhost/moodle/webservice/rest/server.php?wsfunction=core_enrol_get_users_courses&wstoken=a6e17971d60ddcd8f7ea648a605cebb8&userid=4

the answer is in XML format and not in JSON format.
What I need to do to set up JSON format?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved by myself using moodlewsrestformat=json at the end of the http request

http://localhost/moodle/webservice/rest/server.php?wsfunction=core_enrol_get_users_courses&wstoken=a6e17971d60ddcd8f7ea648a605cebb8&userid=4&moodlewsrestformat=json